# How to exclude folder in gulp task for images?

Tags: javascript, gulp

I am using Gulp 4 for my frontend projects. I am want to exclude "fav" folder in "img" folder for gulp-imagemin. How can I do this? This is my project structure:

[structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LO55h.png)

This is my gulpfile.js:

```
var paths = {
    html: {
        src: "src/**/*.html",
        dest: "dest/"
    },

    styles: {
        src: "src/styles/**/*.sass",
        dest: "dest/styles/"
    },

    scripts: {
        src: "src/js/**/*.js",
        dest: "dest/js/"
    },

    images: {
        src: "src/img/**/*.*",
        dest: "dest/img/"
    }
};

function images() {
    return gulp.src(paths.images.src)
        .pipe(imagemin({
            progressive: true,
            interlaced: true,
            use: [pngquant()],
        }))
        .pipe(svgo())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.images.dest));
}
```

Thanks and happy coding!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also try using [gulp-filter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-filter):

```
const filter = require('gulp-filter');

// function images() {
gulp.task('images', function () {

  // restore option lets us bring back the removed files later
  const f = filter(paths.images.exclude, { restore: true });

  return gulp.src(paths.images.src)

    // filter out, remove, files in the fav directory
    .pipe(f)

    // do stuff to remaining files (not including fav/*.*)
    .pipe(imagemin({
      progressive: true,
      interlaced: true,
      use: [pngquant()],
    }))
    .pipe(svgo())

    // Bring back the files previously removed from the stream
    .pipe(f.restore)

    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.images.dest));
});

var paths = {
  images: {
    src: "src/img/**/*.*",
    exclude: ["src/img/**/*.*", "!src/img/fav/*.*"],
    dest: "dest/img/"
  }
};

gulp.task('default', ['images']);
```

[Written in gulp3.9 style since that is what I have in my test bed.]

But I do agree that in this case it may be better to just make two tasks as @Abijeet suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I would try the following,

```
images: {
    src: ["src/img/**/*.*"],
    dest: "dest/img/"
}
```

I haven't tested this, but I think that should work. Notice the `!`, that tells Gulp to ignore those files.

#### Update based on comment

Undo the previous changes made to `images.src`.

To do that I would recommend that you use another process after you've copied the files to dest.

Update the paths array with another object as follows,

```
minify: {
   src: ["dest/img/**/*.*", "!dest/img/fav/*.*"],
   dest: ["dest/img/"]
}


function minify() {
    return gulp.src(paths.minify.src)
        .pipe(imagemin({
            progressive: true,
            interlaced: true,
            use: [pngquant()],
        }))
        .pipe(svgo())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.minify.dest));
}
```

That should work. I'm not sure though if that's the best way to do it, so I'd wait for someone else to answer.

Comment: gulp must build all images from src to dest, but imagemin must don't touch images in fav folder

Comment: This is not helps me, imagemin continues optimizing fav folder

Comment: Made one more edit, see if that helps. I'm assuming you've added one more task after `images()`

Answer (score 0):

Use ! to select everything that doesn't match a path, in conjunction with the normal path.

```
images: {
    src: ["src/img/**/*.*", "!src/img/fav/*.*"]
    dest: "dest/img/"
}
```

Comment: This is doesn't working, gulp must build all images from src to dest, but imagemin must don't touch images in fav folder